# Properties of Injective Operator on Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, system-identification

I am new to functional analysis and have the following issue:

Given an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ and an operator $f: H \times \Omega \to H$, where $\Omega$ is some finite dimensional vector space, how can one determine if $f$ is injective? That is, is it possible that such an operator could be one-to-one?

Any good references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times l_2 (\mathbb{R} ) \to l_2 $ $$ f((x_1 ,x_2 , ..., x_n ) , (y_i )_{n\geq 1} ) = (x_1 ,x_2 , ..., x_n , y_1 , y_2 , ...)$$
then $f$ is injective.

Comment: This is a good example, but do you have some conditions or references? What if $H$ is uncountably infinite, e.g. $L^2$?

Comment: Every Hilbert (infinite dimensional ) contains a isometric copy of $l_2$ e.g

Comment: Every Hilbert space $H$ is isometric to some $l_2 (\mathfrak{m} ) $ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is some cardinal number $l_2$ e.g there is a isometry $I: l_2 (\mathfrak{ m} ) \to H,$ hence if you find a injection fo $ h: \mathbb{R}^n \times l_2 (\mathfrak{m} ) \to l_2 (\mathfrak{m} ) $ then you can define an injecton from $\mathbb{R}^n \times H$ to $H.$

Comment: Interesting, but say I have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times H \to H$. How do I determine that this function is an injection? Does your logic work in the other direction?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. In general a linear operator $T$ is an injection if and only if $T(x)=0\Leftrightarrow x=0$